# Objective-c I get NSObject doesNotRegognizeSelector even though I checked with RespondsToSelector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, callback

I have been trying to write a delegate to a view controller which has a method which will call back the sender when it is done

```
-(void) doSomething:(id)target action:(SEL)action object:(id)object{
  //Do Some work
  //Produce an NSArray* called array
  object = array;
  if([target respondsToSelector:action])
    {
      [target action];
    }
}
```

The idea being that the action method in the sender also has a reference to object and it can read the results and do something once the selector has been called to use the data.

The problem I am having is that [target respondsToSelector:action] returns true so the code tries to call the selector but then I get an SIGABRT signal and the message that NSObject -doesNotRegogniseSelector.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Further to that i am setting the contents of object to an array, but that doesn't appear to have changed in the callback method... any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[target performSelector:action];
```

Typing `[target action]` is not how to dynamically call a method. It would be like calling `[anObject @selector(doSomething)]`. Also, it's probably not needed to check whether `target` responds to `selector`, since your method is being called with those as parameters, and it would be a mistake on the caller's part to pass in a bad selector.

Comment: Further to that i am setting the contents of object to an array, but that doesn't appear to have changed in the callback method... any tips?

Comment: Setting `object = array` does nothing to the caller. It's like passing in `parameter:(int)x` and then setting `x = 42`. The caller has no way of knowing it's set to 42. You could pass in a NSMutableArray and then copy the objects from `array` to `object`.

Answer (score 2):

You should uses `- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector` to call the selector.